# Does factory resetting a rooted phone unroot it?

Tags: root-access, factory-reset, unrooting, cyanogenmod

Does factory resetting a rooted phone unroot it? Does it vary by ROM - I'm on CyanogenMod 11 M7 Nexus 4, will it?